# Inverting a Hash's Key and Values in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to make the value the key, and the key the value. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of multiple keys that map to the same value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adapted from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/46400-swap-hash-values/:

Assuming your hash is stored in `$hash`:

```
while (($key, $value) = each %hash) {
   $hash2{$value}=$key;
}

%hash=%hash2;
```

**Seems like much more elegant solution can be achieved with reverse** (http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-hashes.html#reverseph):

```
%nhash = reverse %hash;
```

Note that with reverse, duplicate values will be overwritten.

Comment: the reverse way is nice, but it has some cavets (pasted directly from the perl docs):  If a value is duplicated in the original hash, only one of those can be represented as a key in the inverted hash. Also, this has to unwind one hash and build a whole new one, which may take some time on a large hash, such as from a DBM file.

Comment: Completely agreed. In trivial cases i think reverse is great, but it is not a universal solution as you highlighted.

Comment: Duplicate values are overwritten with the while-loop version as well.

Comment: Of course they are, but within a while-loop you can more easily add code to handle duplicates...

Comment: I tested this. "reverse" uses slightly more memory than your "while" solution. The reverse solution is much quicker for small hashes, and generally a little quicker, because reverse is built in. For really big hashes, reverse is slower due to memory use. But the hashes themselves are much larger than the temporary memory needed by reverse. It would be a mistake to use reverse to copy between two huge tied 'virtual hashes' such as DBM files. The 'map' method uses the most memory and runs slowest. In general, I would use reverse.

Answer (score 17):

Use [`reverse`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ('month', 'may', 'year', '2011');
print Dumper \%hash;
%hash = reverse %hash;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned, the simplest is

```
my %inverse = reverse %original;
```

It "fails" if multiple elements have the same value. You could create an HoA to handle that situation.

```
my %inverse;
push @{ $inverse{ $original{$_} } }, $_ for keys %original;
```

Comment: It would be conveniet to have an `invert()` method in `Hash::Util` that defaulted to pushing a HoA - or so did when it detected there were duplicate values. Maybe a `perlcritic` warning that keys were being overwritten by duplicates that suggested `push @{ $inverted{ { $hash{$_} }}, $_ for keys %hash;` would be better.   [Perl6's  `.invert` method requires `push` to avoid the overwritten duplicate issue](http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/different-names-of-different-things/) as well.

Comment: I guess there are patterns where you *want* duplicate values to overwritten into one key when reversing a hash.

Answer (score 3):

So you want reverse keys & vals in a  hash? So use reverse... ;)

```
%hash2 = reverse %hash;
```

reverting (k1 => v1, k2 => v2) - yield (v2=>k2, v1=>k1) - and that is what you want. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
my %orig_hash = (...);
my %new_hash;

%new_hash = map { $orig_hash{$_} => $_ } keys(%orig_hash);
```

Comment: Who said its wrong, just showing another way to do this, since reverse was already mentioned (-:

Answer (score 1):

The map-over-keys solution is more flexible. What if your value is not a simple value?

```
my %forward;
my %reverse;

#forward is built such that each key maps to a value that is a hash ref:
#{ a => 'something', b=> 'something else'}

%reverse = map { join(',', @{$_}{qw(a b)}) => $_ } keys %forward;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using [`Hash::MultiValue`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::MultiValue).

```
use experimental qw(postderef);

sub invert {
  use Hash::MultiValue;
  my $mvh = Hash::MultiValue->from_mixed(shift);

  my $inverted;    
  $mvh->each( sub { push $inverted->{ $_[1] }->@* , $_[0] } ) ;
  return $inverted;
}
```

To test this we can try the following:

```
my %test_hash = (
  q => [qw/1 2 3 4/],
  w => [qw/4 6 5 7/],
  e => ["8"],
  r => ["9"],
  t => ["10"],
  y => ["11"],
);

my $wow  = invert(\%test_hash);
my $wow2 = invert($wow);

use DDP;
print "\n \%test_hash:\n\n" ;
p %test_hash;
print "\n \%test_hash inverted as:\n\n" ;
p $wow ;

# We need to sort the contents of the multi-value array reference
# for the is_deeply() comparison:
map { 
   $test_hash{$_} = [ sort { $a cmp $b || $a <=> $b } @{ $test_hash{$_} } ] 
} keys %test_hash ; 

map { 
   $wow2->{$_} = [ sort { $a cmp $b || $a <=> $b } @{ $wow2->{$_} } ] 
} keys %$wow2 ; 

use Test::More ;
is_deeply(\%test_hash, $wow2, "double inverted hash == original");
done_testing;
```

---

### Addendum

Note that in order to pass the gimmicky test here, the `invert()` function relies on `%test_hash` having array references as values.  To work around this if your hash values are not array references, you can "coerce" the regular/mixed hash into a multi-value hash that`Hash::MultiValue` can then bless into an object. However, this approach means even single values will appear as array references:

```
for ( keys %test_hash )  { 
     if ( ref $test_hash{$_} ne 'ARRAY' ) { 
           $test_hash{$_}  = [ $test_hash{$_} ] 
     } 
}
```

which is longhand for:

```
ref($_) or $_ = [ $_ ] for values %test_hash ;
```

This would only be needed to get the "round trip" test to pass.

Comment: Thanks to mst and #perl-help for the shorthand :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your values are simple and unique strings, here is one more easy way to do it.

```perl
%hash = ( ... );
@newhash{values %hash} = (keys %hash);
```

This is called a hash slice.  Since you're using `%newhash` to produce a list of keys, you change the `%` to a `@`.

Unlike the `reverse()` method, this will insert the new keys and values in the same order as they were in the original hash.  `keys` and `values` always return their values in the same order (as does `each`).

If you need more control over it, like sorting it so that duplicate values get the desired key, use two hash slices.

```perl
%hash = ( ... );
@newhash{ @hash{sort keys %hash} } = (sort keys %hash);
```